# setChecked Radio Button not working properly

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I would like to have my android app have a radio button checked using a switch statement. I have confirmed that the string being passed matches one of the cases and still nothing is checked. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.year);
        fre = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.freshmen);
        soph = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.sophomore);
        jun = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.junior);
        sen = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.senior);
        male = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        female = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        lgbtq = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);

        switch (global.getGender()) {
            case "Male": male.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case "Female": female.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case "LGBTQ": lgbtq.setChecked(true);
                break;

        }
        switch (global.getYear()) {
            case "Fresh": fre.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case "Soph": soph.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case "Junior": jun.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case "Senior": sen.setChecked(true);
                break;
        }
```

and in XML

```
   <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/year"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bio"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fresh"
        android:id="@+id/freshmen"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText8"
        android:buttonTint="#00F2EA"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Soph    "
        android:buttonTint="#009B40"
        android:id="@+id/sophomore"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Junior"
        android:buttonTint="#FF0000"
        android:id="@+id/junior"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Senior"
        android:buttonTint="#000"
        android:id="@+id/senior"
        />
</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/gender"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_above="@+id/year"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Male "
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:buttonTint="#076EB9"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Female"
        android:buttonTint="#FF00AA"

        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LGBTQ"
        android:buttonTint="#bf00ff"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton2" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code above was correct. The issue was that the snippet was that I did not understand the architecture of a fragment class.